# ListView checkbox issue after check

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

My issue is that when I check `Checkbox` it turns to checked but it duplicates checked state for next `ListView` item which isn't on the visible list (e.g. when I can see item on positions 0-5/6 on one screen it is for element on position 7-8)...

This is my onClick method:

```
viewHolder.messageSelectBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (viewHolder.messageSelectBox.isChecked()) {
                    Log.i("itemID", String.valueOf(getItemId(position)));
                    Log.i("position", String.valueOf(position));
                    mListOfItemsToDelete.add(position);
                    Collections.sort(mListOfItemsToDelete);
                    Collections.reverse(mListOfItemsToDelete);
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mListOfItemsToDelete.size(); i++) {
                        int pos = mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i);
                        if (pos == position) {
                            mListOfItemsToDelete.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

`setOnClickListener` is in `getView()` in ListView Adapter...

`getView()` method:

```
final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_list_view_single, parent, false);
        }

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

        viewHolder.messageSelectBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageSelectBox);
```

So guys, have you got any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()` you have to load the checked state as following before `setOnClickListener`.

```
viewHolder.messageSelectBox.setChecked(mListOfItemsToDelete.contains(position))
```

so the checked state will be maintained in `mListOfItemsToDelete` and using that state you will be loaded the checked state for the checkbox.

Comment: Works perfectly! I already started to created a new ListView from tutorial... Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common issue with list view. this issue is occurring because   list item is reused when u scroll the list view. So you need to handle each and every time.

for that you need a Boolean value in your model class. and set the value of Boolean to true/false when check box is checked or not.